# How do I debug a crawled/cached link without Facebook's URL linter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that once I publish a link to Facebook, a crawler will visit the link and gather information from the og meta tags and cache it. Using Facebooks [*debugger*](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I can force a refresh of the cached information when I change the share image for example.

If I try to call a URL like `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com` programmatically or directly while not being logged in, a login page is returned.

Is there a resource or different link I can use to force a refresh of the content without doing it manually on a developer account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#update:

> When an action is published, or a Like button pointing to the object
> clicked, Facebook will 'scrape' the HTML page of the object and read
> the meta tags. The object scrape also occurs when:
>
> - The object URL is input in the Object Debugger
> - Every 7 days after the first scrape
> - When an app triggers a scrape using an API endpoint
>
> This Graph API endpoint is simply a call to:
>
> `POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true`

Comment: Update: It does is automatically every 30 days, as of december 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I wrote a WordPress plugin that does just that for published, scheduled and updated posts.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-url-linter-for-posts/