# How to force FaceBook deleting cache?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching

I've just added  tags on my website. But FaceBook uses some old cache data from my website - it means when user shares a post wia FB, there is no thumbnail image in it.

I can fix it 2 ways: a) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/. After I press "Fetch new scrape information" cache data deletes, and all users are sharing with a thumbnail. b) Share a post by myself - then the next sharing would be with thumbnail

Is there any way to force delete FaceBook cache for all posts?

I've tried:

- www.mywebsite.com?fbrefresh=1
- parsing https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://mywebsite.com/&fbrefresh=8

Comment: What you've done to reset the cache looks right. Maybe your tags aren't set up correctly. Can you give an example of your page?

Comment: Here is an example http://gorillafeed.com/so-this-happened/, but the problem is not in tags, because everything works fine after 1 time sharing, or cleaning up the cache in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug a crawled/cached link without Facebook's URL linter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836618/how-do-i-debug-a-crawled-cached-link-without-facebooks-url-linter)

Comment: Tahnk you! tried also, no result